# Can I make characters uncopyable in a terminal emulator?

Tags: terminal, clipboard, terminal-emulator, special-characters

I run fish (in gnome-terminal) with a custom style that gives me information about the current Git repository:

[image]

That's all very fine, but when I want to copy-paste some command with its output like so:

[image]

I *want* to get

```
$ du -sh . 
1012K   .
```

instead of

```
$ du -sh .            0⚹  0↺  0 0≡    master 
1012K   .
```

Another use case would be copying from editors like vim with line numbers enabled -- a major pain in the behind.

Is there any way to prevent selection/copy of certain characters in a terminal?

---

FWIW, I'm aware that some styles move the caret to the next line:

```
<gutter left>           <gutter right>
$ <caret>
```

While a functional workaround, this is not what I'm asking for.

Comment: For practical purposes, [Warp seems to circumvent the issue](https://twitter.com/zachlloydtweets/status/1415343357438615558).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible with the command and its output. The terminal emulator copies whatever is onscreen. You need to copy-paste in two steps: once for the command and once for its output. A terminal *could* make it easier by allowing to select a non-contiguous region of text, like Firefox does on Ctrl+click, but I'm not aware of any terminal implementing this.

As for text editors and line numbers, this is still not possible as long as it's the terminal emulator that copies the text. However, here it might make more sense to use the copying feature of the editor itself (via keyboard or mouse). The editor could not only skip the line number, but also include parts of the text that are chopped at the right margin, preserve TAB characters, preserve other non-printable control characters etc.

Comment: That doesn't sound promising. That said, I just noticed that in some "GUI" terminal applications such as aptitude and htop, you can't select any text. Is that because they are redrawn continously, or do they capture mouse events somehow? Could e.g. fish hack the area through the terminal emulator? (Maybe this is not the best place for such a conversation.)

Comment: Aptitude and htop capture mouse events themselves. You can still select using Shift+mouse in most terminals.

Comment: "Could e.g. fish hack the area through the terminal emulator?" Not really. Whether mouse is captured is global for the entire terminal at a time, not specific to some area. It could capture mouse events when you're editing a command line, but not when a command (e.g. "sleep 10") is running. And it could only select under its own area (the prompt and the command being edited) because it's unaware of the rest of the text. It probably couldn't even work on its previous prompts and command lines because it would be unaware of their vertical positioning. So no, forget this.

Comment: I see, how unfortunate. Thanks! I guess the only alternative are HTML/JS terminal emulators then... :/

Comment: How would HTML/JS terminal emulators help you here?

Comment: On websites, it's possible to control what gets selected when in more detail than line-by-line. One would have to figure out if and how to automatisms in typical terminal output can work, but at least it's possible in principle.

Comment: Do you mean selecting multiple segments with Ctrl+click in Firefox? Sure that saves a tiny bit of work. Just wondering: Is copy-pasting a command along with its output really such a typical part of your everyday workflow that it's worth it to switch to an entirely different way of launching the terminal to make it a tiny bit easier? Have you considered just switching to a much simpler prompt?

Comment: I do it often enough to be annoyed, but not nearly enough to bear the pain of an Electron-driven terminal emulator (which is travesty). For now, I'll have to live with the disappointment that in several decades of GUI terminals, nobody thought to invent special characters to better control graphical interaction with terminal outputs.

Comment: Regarding what I had in mind, consider the [current gist.github.com UI](https://i.imgur.com/RMgRQ46.png). With a single mouse selection, I can grab description, title, and code without inadvertantly copying any of the icons, buttons, or line numbers (which are very useful UI elements). A similarly structured shell output would be all but impossible to copy-paste. That said, I realize now that I'm asking for a fundamentally different approach to terminal emulation (and output design) than what we currently have.

Comment: "fundamentally different approach to terminal emulation" – yes.